# Exception while invoking update method with Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

What's causing this error to show, all code is correct, show I use update instead of dealsUpdates

> Exception while invoking method 'deals.update' ReferenceError:
>   dealsUpdates is not definedat [object
>   Object].Meteor.methods.deals.update (imports/api/deals.js:125:12)

Comment: what's happening at line 125 of deals.js?

Comment: That is where the 'deals.update' takes place

Comment: post the relevant code

Comment: Hey, sorry I'll try close this question I got it fixed :)